# Why does my Expect script only echo the command not running?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, automation, expect

I'm trying to automate some `ssh` process. I have my Expect code. But my Expect code only echos/prints out the command. It doesn't actually run the command.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 10
set usrnm "aaaaaa"
set pwd "pppppp"
set addr1 "xxx.cloud.xxx.com -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
set addr2 "xxx.xxxx.xxxx.com"

spawn ssh $usrnm@$addr1

expect {

    "(yes/no)?" {send "yes\r";exp_continue}

    "password: " {send  "$pwd\r"}

}


expect "*#"
send "ssh $usrnm@$addr2\r"

expect {

    "(yes/no)?" {send "yes\r";exp_continue}

    "password:" {send  "$pwd\r"}

}

expect "*#"

send "cd /tmp/myself/folder\r"

expect "*#"

send "./run_engine.sh test.py\r"

expect eof

#interact
```

So if I do

```
expect my_expect.exp
```

it just prints the command:

`spawn ssh aaaaaa@xxx.cloud.xxx.com -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
(10s later)
ssh aaaaa@xxx.xxxx.xxxx.com
(10s later)
cd /tmp/amz337/COAFALV
(10s later)
./run_engine.sh test.py
(exit)`

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: Some tangential advice: Using SSH key authentication would a) be much safer, b) allow you to use plain shell scripts instead of `expect`, and c) therefore be much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Tcl (and thus Expect) does not change the word boundaries when variables get substituted. You are trying to log into the host named exactly:

```
xxx.cloud.xxx.com -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

spaces and all.

Logically, it does not make sense to put `ssh` options into a variable that holds the address. May I suggest:

```
set addr1 "xxx.cloud.xxx.com"
set addr2 "xxx.xxxx.xxxx.com"
set ssh_opts($addr1) {-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no}
set ssh_opts($addr2) {}
```

Then

```
spawn ssh {*}$ssh_opts($addr1) $usrnm@$addr1
```

The `{*}` syntax is Tcl's "splat" operator that splits a word with spaces into the individual words. See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm rule #5.

Later, when you connect to the second machine, you're interpolating into a string, so the splat is not necessary:

```
send "ssh $ssh_opts($addr2) $usrnm@$addr2\r"
```

You might want to catch timeout events and abort the script:

```
expect {
    timeout      {error "timed-out connecting to $addr1"}
    "(yes/no)?"  {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    "password: " {send  "$pwd\r"}
}
```

At the end of your script, after the run_engine script completes, you're still connected to addr2, so `expect eof` will not actually detect EOF on the spawned process. You'll timeout after 10 seconds and the Expect process will exit. For tidiness, you should:

```
send "./run_engine.sh test.py\r"
expect "*#"
send "exit\r"
# This prompt is from addr1
expect "*#"
send "exit\r"
# _Now_ the spawned ssh process will end
expect eof
```

If you think the run_engine script will take longer than 10 seconds, you should adjust the timeout variable before sending that command.

Also, while developing an Expect script, you should turn on debugging:

```
exp_internal 1
```

That will show you what's going on behind the scenes, especially when it comes to seeing if your patterns are matching.